# CCPROXY with CURL

Tags: php, curl, http-status-code-302

I'm trying to program a script to use CURL as billing software and modify information on CCproxy web Panel.

But I have a problem:

This is my code :

```
$url="http://xxxxxxx:88/account";
$postfields["form"] = "1";
$postfields["adminpassword"] = "newpassword";
$postfields["changeadminpassword"] = "Modify";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'admin:password');


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);


$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $data;
```

When I used it without post and postfield option then I can echo all user list form ccproxy web panel and its just show page source code with this http response:

**HTTP/1.0 200 OK Server: CCProxy Pragma: no-cache,no-store Cache-control: no-cache,no-store Connection: close Content-length: 200107 Content-type: text/html**

its good for the start but when I try to use postfields and post method I receive http 302 error and nothing work , this is the http response :

**HTTP/1.1 302 Found Server: CCProxy 6.6 Pragma: no-cache,no-store Cache-control: no-cache,no-store Location: /account**

Would you please tell me how can I post queries to ccproxy web panel to modify users or any thing else !

**As I checked the HTML Form, the action field is "account" and method is "post"**

Also when I create .html file with this source code its work !

```
<form action="http://xxxxxx:88/account" method="post" name="form">
<input type="text" value="newpassword" name="adminpassword">
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Modify" name="changeadminpassword">
</form>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

302 is a redirect http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302

Try adding this setting

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

Comment: I receive this response : HTTP/1.1 302 Found Server: CCProxy 6.6 Pragma: no-cache,no-store Cache-control: no-cache,no-store Location: /account HTTP/1.0 200 OK Server: CCProxy Pragma: no-cache,no-store Cache-control: no-cache,no-store Connection: close Content-length: 201982 Content-type: text/html

Comment: As well its show source code but post action does not affected !